# AuthenticationManager missing when using spring.security with grpc-spring-boot-starter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, grpc-java

I am using OpenApi to generate java client code using a spring webclient.
This offers an MergedApi class .

```java
@Bean
public MergedApi mergedApi(final ApiClient apiClient) {
  return new MergedApi(apiClient);
}
```

To add my token to the ApiClient, I need to use following dependencies:

```xml
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-starter-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Unfortunately needed because spring boot does not offer all the necessary classes to shove my token down MergedApi's throat

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-oauth2-client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Needed for enabling spring boot to make calls to REST-Endpoints

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            <version></version>
        </dependency>
```

Needed for grpc.

```xml
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.github.lognet</groupId>
                <artifactId>grpc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-grpc-starter.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
```

When I start the application I get the message:

```
Error creating bean with name 'springGrpcSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/lognet/springboot/grpc/security/GrpcSecurityConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An AuthenticationManager is required
```

On my debugging journey to hell and back, I stumbled across this beauty in `org.lognet.springboot.grpc.security.GrpcSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```java
  @Override
  public void configure(GrpcSecurity builder) throws Exception {
    try {
      final Class<?> jwtDecoderClass =
          Class.forName("org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder");
      final String[] beanNames = context.getBeanNamesForType(jwtDecoderClass);
      if (1 == beanNames.length) {
        builder.authenticationProvider(
            JwtAuthProviderFactory.forAuthorities(context.getBean(beanNames[0], JwtDecoder.class)));
      }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    }
    // swallow
    builder.authorizeRequests().withSecuredAnnotation();
  }
```

So apparently when no JwtDecoder-Bean exists, the whole Application crashed and thankfully this error is thrown somewhere completely else since this catch block is empty.
I added manually the JwtDecoder and the necessary dependency for it:

```java
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder decoder() {
        return token -> Jwt.withTokenValue(token).build();
    }
```

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-starter-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Is there a depdendency which I am missing? Why does this problem occur? Why do I need a JwtDecoder here (apart from being mandatory in the code)?
Is there any good tutorial on how to use java client code generated by OpenApi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Put `grpc.security.auth.enabled = false` in application.properties/yaml.

Reason:

The [docs](https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter#spring-security-integration) say:

> Autoconfigures and runs the embedded gRPC server with @GRpcService-enabled beans as part of spring-boot application (short video)

> GRPC security configuration follows the same principals and APIs as Spring WEB security configuration, it’s enabled by default if you have org.springframework.security:spring-security-config dependency in your classpath.

> By setting grpc.security.auth.enabled to false, GRPC security can be turned-off.

I didn't understand it a couple days ago, but as soon as `security:spring-security-config` exists in your class path, `grpc-spring-boot-starter` will attempt to build an `GrpcSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

The flow is as follows:

- `JwtDecoder`
- needed in
- `GrpcSecurityConfigurerAdapter`
- is configured in
- `GrpcSecurityConfiguration`
- imported in
- `EnableGrpcSecurity`-Annotation
- used in
- `GrpcSecurityEnablerConfiguration`
- Imported in
- `SecurityAutoConfiguration`
- which is conditional on class
- `AuthenticationConfiguration`
- which is proudly autoconfigured and build by
- `spring-security-config`

Just the use of `spring-security-config` (as the docs state, which I was too dumb to understand) triggers the gRPC authentication feature.

Answer (score 1):

For those who interested here  is the [link to discussion](https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter/pull/363#issuecomment-1616053369) .

- I'm the  author of `LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could see from https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter, this lib is stuck to Spring Boot `2.x` and Spring Security `5.x`.

Other point noticeable from the code you point is that it is adapted to a small subset of possible configuration for Spring OAuth2 resource servers: exactly one single JWT decoder, when it is perfectly legit to have several JWT decoders in multi-tenant scenarios or no JWT decoder at all for resource servers configured with token introspection (the access token is validated by the authorization server which returns associated claims).

In short, I'd avoid this lib... You could have a look at `@FeignClient` for a declarative REST client better integrated with Spring (and kept up to date).

Comment: https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter and https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter appear to be different libraries.
I cannot desist from using lognet/grpc-spring-boot-starter since its already deep down in my code. 

The missing update to springboot 3 is an issue of both libraries.